# Compare list data with static string in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following list,

```
String UpDownStatus = "UP";
List<db1> StockData = new List<db1>(); 
db1 newStock = new db1();
newStock.Date = (DateTime)reader["Date"];
newStock.High = (double)reader["High"];
newStock.Low = (double)reader["Low"];
newStock.Close = (double)reader["Close"];
newStock.Up_Down = (string)reader["Up_Down"];
StockData.Add(newStock);
```

The Up_Down column in my DB has the following two string : "UP" and "DOWN"

how can i compare whether the current value of

```
for (int i = 0; i < StockData.Count; i++)
{
    if(StockData[i].Up_Down.CompareTo(UpDownStatus) != 0)
    { 

       //do something
    }
}
```

I know, i could reframe this statement like if (StockData[i].Up_Down=="UP") but i need a solution where I could use .CompareTo function.

Comment: Why do you want to do this rather than just comapring against a object you set up? What would the UpDownStatus string look like?

Comment: *"i need a solution where I could use .CompareTo function."* Why?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you need and how you want to use `CompareTo`

Comment: Sorry Pikoh, just edited the statement

Comment: Heinzi, is there any other method that you know off ?

Comment: First, why are you using `CompareTo` instead of `==` or `Equals`? Second  If you want to find all instances where `Up_Down` is `UP`, use `StockData.Where(data=>data.Up_Down == "UP")`. No need for a loop. This will return all `StockData` items that match `UP`

Comment: @PrateekDaniels why are you using CompareTo in the first place? If you want to compare for equality use `Equals` or `==`. `CompareTo` is used for sorting only

Comment: From MSDN reference of the ToCompare method: The CompareTo method was designed primarily for use in sorting or alphabetizing operations. It should not be used when the primary purpose of the method call is to determine whether two strings are equivalent. To determine whether two strings are equivalent, call the Equals method.

Comment: @DavideVitali: thanks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thanks mate. suggestion taken

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question right and you want to do something on all items which have the same up/down-status as the variable *UpDownStatus*, this would be the easiest way to do it:

```
    foreach (var item in StockData.Where(e => e.Up_Down == UpDownStatus))
    {
        // do something
    }
```